# Determiner order in sentence

Tags: determiners

I am getting stuck order of determiner to be placed in the sentence. Sharing few examples.

1. Four-times the cost; Determiner “four-times” and “the”, there is no of between them.
2. Three-quarter of the participants; Determiner “three-quarter” and “the”, of placed between them.
3. Some of the girls/some of my friends; Determiner “some”, “the” and “my”: of is placed between them.
4. Some more juice; “some” and “more” quantifiers which are same level quantifiers but there is no words (may be of etc.) placed between them.

I want to understand what is the rule to put multiple determiners (pre, central and post determiners)  before to noun.

Answer (score 1):

In general:

Comparative quantifiers - that by themselves say the numbers or amounts of things in reference to other numbers, go first.  (Both, three-quarters, all, double)

Then, "main" determiners:  articles (a, the), demonstratives (this, that), possessives (my, his, its).  You can only have ONE of these.

Finally you can put other determiners on the end, including order words (next, last, previous), numbers (one, two, three), distinguishers (other), and relative quantifiers that modify others (most, much, many).  The order of these has to be learned.

Here is an article which has a big chart with all the common determiners and their place orders:  [Order of Determiners | Grammar | Englush Club](https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/determiners-order.htm).